# ray class groups in $\Bbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I study class field theory from the book "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$", D. Cox. I want to find ray class groups in $\Bbb{Q}$.

Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathfrak{m}$ be a modulus of $K$. In the book, $I_K(\mathfrak{m})$ is defined as the group of all fractional ideals of $K$ coprime to $\mathfrak{m}_0$ (finite part of $\mathfrak{m}$). $P_K(\mathfrak{m})$ is defined as the subgroup of $I_K(\mathfrak{m})$ generated by the principle ideals $\alpha\mathcal{O}_K$, where $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}_K$ satisfies $\alpha\equiv 1 \ mod \ \mathfrak{m}_0$ and $\sigma(\alpha)> 0$ for every real infinite prime $\sigma$ dividing $\mathfrak{m}_0$ (infinite part of $\mathfrak{m}$).

For example, Set $K=\Bbb{Q}$ and $\mathfrak{m}=(8)$. Then according to the above definitions, I find $$I_\Bbb{Q}((8))=\{(a/b)\Bbb{Z}: gcd(a,8)=gcd(b,8)=1 \}=\{(a/b)\Bbb{Z}: 2\nmid a,b\}$$
$$P_\Bbb{Q}((8))=<a\Bbb{Z}: a\in\Bbb{Z},\  a\equiv 1\ mod\ (8)>=\{(a/b)\Bbb{Z}: a\equiv 1\ mod\ 8, \ b\equiv 1\ mod\ 8\}$$

First , I am not sure that I write these groups correctly. Also, I couldn`t conclude that the ray class group
$Cl_\Bbb{Q}((8)):=I_\Bbb{Q}((8))/P_\Bbb{Q}((8))$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z})^*$. Generally, I have trouble to describe the ray class groups.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that ray class group should be isomorphic to $(\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$

Comment: @sharding4 According to another lecture notes, $I_\Bbb{Q}((8))=\{a/b\Bbb{Z}: a/b \equiv 1,3,5,7 mod 8 \}$ and $P_\Bbb{Q}=\{a/b\Bbb{Z}: a/b\equiv 1 mod\ 8 \}$. Then write $Cl_\Bbb{Q}(8)=\{1,3,5,7 mod8\}/\{1,7 mod8\}\cong (\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z})^*$ But I don`t understand why the groups   are defined like that.

Comment: There's seems to be an error in your lecture notes, because on the one hand $P_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is defined as $\{a/b\Bbb{Z}: a/b\equiv 1 mod\ 8 \}$ but at another point as $\{1,7\bmod 8\}$  It depends on the infinite place.  If ramification at the infinite prime is allowed (i.e. complex extensions) then the ray class field should be the cyclotomic field of eighth roots of unity.  If ramification is not allowed at the infinite prime (the $\{1,7\bmod 8\}$ case where you can multiply by $-1$ because you don's have the $\sigma(a/b)>0$ requirement) then the ray class field is $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$

Comment: @sharding4 Actually , I am concerned just ray class groups, according to the definitions in the Cox`s book, I wonder $I((8))$ and $P((8))$ and what is the ray class group?  Since we choose $\mathfrak{m}=(8)$, I assume the inifinite prime is unramified. I cannot relate these groups to the ones in my comment.

Comment: All the extension fields related to definite quadratic forms would probably have ramification at the infinite prime.

Answer (score 2):

The ray class group modulo $8$ corresponds to the ray class field modulo $8$, which is the maximal totally real abeliab extension of ${\mathbb Q}$ with conductor $8$, i.e., the maximal real subfield of ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta_8)$, namely ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2})$. This is a quadratic extension, as is confirmed by the fact that the ray class group modulo $8$ has order $2$. In fact, the ideal generated by $(3)$ in the ray class group is nor principal, i.e., is not generated by an element $a/b \equiv 1 \bmod 8$. Moreover $(3) = (5)$ since $(5) = (-5) = (3)$ inside the ray class group. Ray class groups over the rationals are basically residue class groups since ${\mathbb Q}$ has class number $1$.

Comment: According to the definition of ray group, I find $P((8))=\{(a/b): a\equiv b\equiv 1mod8\}$ as explained above. But, in another lecture note it is stated directly $P((8))=\{(a/b): a/b\equiv 1mod8\}$ which is equal to $P((8))=\{(a/b): a\equiv b mod8\}$. I don`t understand why I have inconsistent results.

Comment: There is no inconsistency. If $a/b \equiv 1 \bmod 8$, then $a \equiv b \bmod 8$, hence $a^2 \equiv ab \equiv 1 \bmod 8 \bmod 8$ and $a/b = a^2/ab$.

Comment: To be honest, still don`t understand. I used the word consistency because $a\equiv\b\equiv1mod8$ is more rigid  than a\equiv b mod8. So $\{(a/b): a\equiv b\equiv 1mod8\}$ is not equal to $\{(a/b): a\equiv b mod8 \}$

Comment: Congruences in connection with ray class groups are always to be read multiplicatively. If you think the sets are not equal, then give an element that belongs to one and not to the other.

Comment: ok. I convinced myself after some tryings. But how to see $ab\equiv 1 mod8$. Using $a^2\equiv1\mod8$, I dont understand what i have. I hope I don`t bother you but I am really stuck

Comment: If $a \equiv b \bmod 8$, then $ab \equiv a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ since all odd numbers squared leave the remainder $1$ when divided by $8$.